# Обязанности junior C# developer

Tags: работа, c#

Подскажите, что необходимо знать для того, чтобы устроиться junior C# developer.

Answer (score 5):

Пример взят с [RSDN](http://rsdn.ru).

> Общие технические вопросы:
>
> 1. Как вы представляете себя обязанности Senior Developer’а?
> 2. Почему вы хотите работать программистом?
> 3. За счет каких свойств современные средства разработки компании MS способны повысить производительность программиста?
> 4. Каковы отличия между технологиями ADO и ADO.NET?
> 5. Каковы отличия между технологиями ASP.NET, PHP и Perl?
> 6. Что такое полиморфизм?
> 7. Каковы основные концепции ООП?
> 8. Насколько хорошо вы знаете ту или иную технологию?
> 9. Готовы ли вы разбираться в том-то и том-то?
> 10. Какие направления вас интересуют больше (реализация серверной логики, реализация алгоритмов, использование WinWorms, БД)?
> 11. Почему вы выбрали именно такое-то направление (например, .NET, а не С++)?
> 12. Какие эвристики вы применяли при решении этой и этой задачи? Что такое эвристика в принципе?
>
> Технические вопросы:
>
> 1. Модификаторы private и protected. Отличия.
> 2. Какова разница между выражениями: a++ и ++a. Привести пример кода.
> 3. Что такое Generics и какие проблемы они решают?
> 4. Рассказать о модификаторах параметров методов класса: in, out, ref.
> 5. Написать процедуру удаления произвольного элемента из односвязанного списка.
> 6. Написать процедуру реверсирования строки.
> 7. Поменять значения двух переменных типа int, не используя третей переменной.
> 8. Приведение типов в C#.
> 9. Что такое sealed class?
> 10. Что такое abstract class? Отличия от интерфейса.
> 11. Виды типов в С#.
> 12. Для чего нужен интерфейс IDisposable?
> 13. Можно ли переменной типа int задать значение null? Привести пример кода.
> 14. Как установить в единицы самый правый нулевой бит в произвольном целом числе не используя циклов и рекурсии?
> 15. Написать SQL запрос, который выбирает ФИО всех студентов у которых не менее 5 двоек и количество полученных ими пятерок из двух таблиц Students(ID, FIO), Marks(StudID, Mark).
> 16. Написать программу на любом алгоритмическом языке, проверяющую правильность расстановки круглых “()“ и квадратных скобок 
>      “[]” в арифметическом выражении (возможны модификации задачи).
> 17. Чем машина Тьюринга отличается от конечных автоматов?
> 18. Что такое сериализация? Для чего она применяется?
>
> Также будьте готовы к применению UML и паттернов проектирования.

Answer (score 3):

Для подобной должности (Junior - это младший, то есть новичок, начинающий) ничего особенного не нужно: работа во многом не самостоятельная, а под руководством старшего товарища. У нас обычно берут ребят, которые год-два где-нибудь программировали. И даже не обязательно, чтобы они знали C#.